# Why can auto not be used as a return type for function declaration

Tags: c++, c++11, dry, auto

This code does not compile (intel icc 15.0.3) with the error message `explicit type is missing ("int" assumed)`

```
auto foo(){
     const bool retVal = false;
     return retVal;
}
```

It can be easily be seen, that the return type in this case is `bool`. Why can [auto](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/auto) not be used as a return type for function declaration? This feature would nicely support the [DRY principle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself).

Comment: Try C++14. Which allows this.

Comment: The general answer to "why does feature X not exist" is: "No-one got around to implementing it" often with an implicit *yet*

Comment: Or use lambda, which allows it: `auto foo = []() { const bool retVal = false; return retVal; };`

Comment: @Caleth it could also be "because it would conflict with this or that", which isn't uncommon in a language with a consequent history and strong design goals such as C++.

Comment: @Quentin Yes, but that's arguably part of why no-one implemented it. In the case of C++ "implemented it" looks like "wrote a proposal, had it be discussed by the committee, demonstrated a prototype, had it voted into the standard". Some of those steps can fail

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As commented by [Jon](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3726169/jon-chesterfield) and Ron, using a [c++14](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b14) compiler fixes this problem.

In addition, [Aki](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1716339/aki-suihkonen)'s lambda solution would work:

```
auto foo = []() {
  const bool retVal = false;
  return retVal;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

You can could use a trailing return type in C++11, if you want to do it the modern way:

```
auto foo() -> bool{
     const bool retVal = false;
     return retVal;
}
```

But I have to admit, I prefer to use `bool foo(){..}` for pre-C++14.